# iredmail on ubuntu 22.04.3, nginx proxy, roundcube

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, roundcube, iredmail

before that, i've hosted some websites from my synology nas. But now, i need to create a mailserver. 've installed iredmail on ubuntu server, and created a new Nginx server ( on other hw) for the reverse proxy.

I can reach the roundcube from outside ( so the proxy is working correctly), but i cant log-in. I'am getting the following error from outside of the network:

"Invalid request! No data was saved"

From inside its working correctly. I think, the Nginx proxy is doing something ( maybe with the header), what is missing. BTW, i cannot connect to the mail server from phone, or any other device. [topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy7Q7.jpg)

Waiting for the answers,
David

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

've enabled HSTS and solved the problem!